# Excel VBA inserting value from different Worksheet using file path

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to recall a value from different worksheet that contains "-" (hyphen) in folder/file name without changing the name of the folder/the file. (want to use the file path)

```
Sub file_path()
 Dim strFolder As String
 Dim CopySheet As String
 Dim po, iu As String
 Dim DestinationSheet As Variant
 Dim qwer As Workbook
 Dim poi As Workbook
 Dim por As Variant

CopySheet = InputBox("path of workbook you recall")

Set qwer = Workbooks.Open(CopySheet)


po = InputBox("sheet name")
iu = InputBox("Range")

por = qewr.Sheets(po).Range(iu).Value

ActiveCell.Value = vals
po.Close

End Sub
```

I tried using this code but I keep getting error when i put the value for "por" variant. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have declared `po` as Variant, probably without realizing it. Change `Dim po, iu As String` to `Dim po As String, iu As String`. Each variable needs to be declared against itself.

Comment: You should not use `.Value = ArrayVariable`. If you used `ActiveCell = por` then the ActiveCell will get the top left cell value of the array por. Also I believe you will get error on `po.Close`, I think you meant for `qwer.Close`.